# Passing a variable into a filter Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using a filter in my Django Rest Framework project to search for items in a given date range. I would like to pass variables into a url like so: `/?start_date=2022-12-01&end_date=2022-12-06`
but I can't seem to figure out how to insert 'start_date' and 'end_date' as variables you can search. The filter works when I do

`queryset = Search.objects.filter(added_date__range=["2022-12-06", "2022-12-06"])`

but I would like it to be something like:

`queryset = Search.objects.filter(added_date__range=[start_date, end_date])`

Here is the model:

```
class Search(models.Model):
    added_date = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    added_time = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    id = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

View:

```
class SearchViewSet(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            Search.objects.filter(added_date__range=[self.start_date, self.end_date])
        except Exception as exception:
            return Response(response500('No Data Found', exception), status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    def get(self, request):
        self.start_date = request.GET['start_date']
        self.end_date = request.GET['end_date']

        try:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            search_data = SearchSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            resp = {'data': search_data.data}
            response = Response(resp)
            return response
        except Exception as exception:
            return Response(response500('No Data Found', exception), status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Url:

```
re_path(r'search-summary', views.SearchViewSet.as_view(), name='search-summary')
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from `get_queryset()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class based views, you can use `self.request.query_params.get()`. so, for example:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    start_date= self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
    try:
        Search.objects.filter(added_date__range=[start_date, end_date])
    except Exception as exception:
        return Response(response500('No Data Found', exception), status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

If you need to use them elsewhere, then you should still be able to use the same method in `get()` to add them to self.